# multiplication of mixed dataframe with vector

Tags: r, vector, dataframe

R beginner here: After searching for what must be a simple answer for over a day, decided to post my first ever question on here:

I would like to multiply (or divide) numeric columns in a dataframe with a numeric vector. The dataframe contains not just numbers but also strings. In my search I've learned about `t(t(mydf) * myvec))`, `sweep()`, `scale()`, `*apply()` and replacement operations, but I'm having trouble figuring out a clever function to allow me to specify which columns are multiplied without subsetting the dataframe.

How can multiply/divide each row in the last two columns of test.dat with myvec and get back a dataframe that contains the result along with the unaltered columns> (Yes for the numerics I could just add a '1' to myvec). But how do I deal with the names?
Thank you in advance!!

Proper Example:

> mydf <-as.data.frame(rbind(c("chrX", 5624624, 5631869, "Nudt11", 2, "+", 1, 7245, 1.332, 9651.3), c("chrX", 5977262, 6210835, "Shroom4", 9, "+", 1, 233573, 1.357, 316914)))
>
> colnames(mydf)<-c("chr", "start", "end", "name", "score", "strand", "score2", "width", "value", "value2")
>
> myvec<-c(10, 0.0001)

Comment: your `mydf` is a matrix. when you `rbind`, if there is not at least one `data.frame` as input, the output will be "bind" (bound) as a matrix. Use `data.frame(.)` to create your input instead.

Comment: The answers are still be valid, check my edited answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already said, you are not dealing with the `data.frame` in your example. Let's make your data as `data.frame` first:

```
# bind the numerical values as variables (columns) of data.frame
mydf <-as.data.frame(cbind(
 c(1, 10, 3.6, 4.5, 5.4, 99), 
 c(12, 18, 9, 8.1, 7.2, 84)))

# give names to columns: 
names(mydf)<-c("somename","othername")

#multiply the wanted rows with myvec:

mydf[4:6,]<-myvec*mydf[4:6,]
mydf
  somename othername
1  1.00000  12.00000
2 10.00000  18.00000
3  3.60000   9.00000
4 40.50000  72.90000
5 54.00000  72.00000
6 16.50033  14.00028
```

EDIT: Again, your example data is not a data.frame, but after tweaking it to proper data frame where the numeric values really are numbers and not factors, this still works:

```
mydf[,9:10]<-myvec*mydf[,9:10]
mydf
   chr   start     end    name score strand score2  width     value     value2
1 chrX 5624624 5631869  Nudt11     2      +      1   7245 1.332e+01 96513.0000
2 chrX 5977262 6210835 Shroom4     9      +      1 233573 1.357e-04    31.6914
```

So you can choose whatever columns you want by using square brackets, just make sure the length of `myvec` is equal to the number of columns so you won't get any suprising results due to recycling.

Comment: Thank you, @Hemmo. There is something I'm missing about the proper dataframe. R tells me it is, how did you tweak it? thanks!

Comment: > class(mydf)
[1] "data.frame"

Comment: I tried the following to tweak, but it changed the order of the last column (row2 now before row1):

Comment: transform(mydf, value = as.numeric(levels(value)), value2= as.numeric(levels(value2)))

Comment: Aha:   mydf2<-transform(mydf, value = as.numeric(paste(value)), value2= as.numeric(paste(value2)))

Comment: I'm very happy. If I could upvote this I would, but i can't yet. Thank you, Hemmo!

Comment: @Stefan Your way of doing the data frame in the example makes the numeric values as factors as you mix them with strings in `c(...)`. You should bind your variables together column by column using cbind, or like this `mydf<-data.frame(chr=c("chrX","chrX"),start=c(5624624, 5631869),...)`

Comment: Yes, that mistake was due to some major holes in my even most basic understanding of R. The way you wrote it makes complete sense to me. I just checked, when I actually read-in the data-frame from file everything is already in the proper type. Thank you so much - this was a great first experience on stack overflow!

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to change your character matrix `mydf` (it's not a data frame) to a data frame with named columns:

```
mydf2 <- setNames(as.data.frame("mode<-"(t(mydf[ , -1]), "numeric")), mydf[ , 1])

> mydf2
  somename othername
1      1.0      12.0
2     10.0      18.0
3      3.6       9.0
4      4.5       8.1
5      5.4       7.2
6     99.0      84.0
```

Then it will be easy to apply the multiplication with `myvec`:

```
res <- lapply(mydf2[4:6, ], "*", myvec)
```

Replace the values with the new values:

```
mydf2[4:6, ] <- res

> mydf2
  somename othername
1  1.00000  12.00000
2 10.00000  18.00000
3  3.60000   9.00000
4 40.50000  72.90000
5 54.00000  72.00000
6 16.50033  14.00028
```

**Update**

Based on your edit, here's a way to do it:

```
last2 <- tail(seq_along(mydf), 2) # find the index of the last two columns

# transform columns from factor to numeric and multiplicate with vector
res <- lapply(lapply(mydf[last2], 
                     function(x) as.numeric(as.character(x))), "*", myvec)

mydf[last2] <- res # replace values

> mydf
   chr   start     end    name score strand score2  width     value     value2
1 chrX 5624624 5631869  Nudt11     2      +      1   7245 1.332e+01 96513.0000
2 chrX 5977262 6210835 Shroom4     9      +      1 233573 1.357e-04    31.6914
```

Comment: Wow. That was fast. Thank you, @SvenHohenstein. You're completely right, I just wrote up a quick example. I am actually working with a dataframe, and unfortunately it has more than one non-numeric column. Will this solution still work as long as the numeric columns i want to multiply are adjacent to each other so I can specify the range [4:6,]? Vielen Dank!

Comment: @Stefan Yes, this solution will work for all numeric columns. You can also specify non-adjacent columns, e.g., `[4:6, c(1, 3, 5:7)]`.

Comment: @SvenHohenstein any reason you prefer `lapply` over simple multiplication like in my solution?

Comment: @Hemmo No, I simply missed this possibility. Of course it's simpler and more readable.

Comment: If all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail ;)

Comment: Thank you both Sven and @Hemmo. I realize now I shoud have posted my actual example, rather than a toy one. Here are two rows of the actual data - I only want to multiply the last two columns but get back the dataframe with all the info:

Comment: It's really hard to get your data out of that comment, please post it in the actual question (there is just the name of the file now).

Comment: Yes, sorry, just figured out how to do this. It's up now. Thank you so much!

Comment: Thank you so much, Sven, that works, I just needed to switch the multiplier to work by column not row, as such:

Comment: last2 <- tail(seq_along(mydf), 2)

Comment: mydf[last2]<-t(myvec*t(mydf[last2]))

Comment: I'm very happy. If I could upvote this I would, but i can't yet. Thank you, Sven!